# Repopulate Tab with new data

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code below that consists of a `HTML Tab` populated with my multidimensional array i created a `Update Data!` button to try to repopulate my `Tab` with the new data in my `updateTab` function the problem is whenever i click on the `button` it just appends the new data below my original data. I would like to ask if anyone has any suggestion on how to `repopulate` the `Tabs Data` and not appending it at the bottom. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```js
function updateTab() {
  var anotherArr = [];
  var person5 = {
    ["first-Name"]: "Jun",
    ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
    ["age"]: 18,
    ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
  };
  var person6 = {
    ["first-Name"]: "Scooby",
    ["last-Name"]: "Doo",
    ["age"]: 18,
    ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
  };
  var person7 = {
    ["first-Name"]: "Seiya",
    ["last-Name"]: "Shun",
    ["age"]: 18,
    ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
  };
  var person8 = {
    ["first-Name"]: "Ikki",
    ["last-Name"]: "Hyuga",
    ["age"]: 18,
    ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
  };
  anotherArr.push(person5, person6, person7, person8);

  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  anotherArr.forEach((person, i) => {
    var name = document.createElement('h4');
    var desc = document.createElement('p');
    var button = document.createElement('div');
    name.className = "lol";
    name.textContent = `${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
    desc.textContent = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
    frag.appendChild(name);
    frag.appendChild(desc);

  });
  parent.appendChild(frag);
}


var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["first-Name"]: "John",
  ["last-Name"]: "Doe",
  ["age"]: 21,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};
var person3 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Sean",
  ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
  ["age"]: 32,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person4 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Ken",
  ["last-Name"]: "Chow",
  ["age"]: 12,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var name = document.createElement('h4');
  var desc = document.createElement('p');
  var button = document.createElement('div');

  name.textContent = `${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
  desc.textContent = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
  frag.appendChild(name);
  frag.appendChild(desc);

});
parent.appendChild(frag);


function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.size {
  width: 50%;
}

a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

.lol {
  color: lime;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="size">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
    </div>
    <div id="People" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="line1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="updateTab()">Update Data!</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just empty the contents before appending the new fragment? Right before `parent.appendChild(frag)`, simply add `parent.innerHTML = ""`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function updateTab() {
  var anotherArr = [];
  var person5 = {
    ["first-Name"]: "Jun",
    ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
    ["age"]: 18,
    ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
  };
  var person6 = {
    ["first-Name"]: "Scooby",
    ["last-Name"]: "Doo",
    ["age"]: 18,
    ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
  };
  var person7 = {
    ["first-Name"]: "Seiya",
    ["last-Name"]: "Shun",
    ["age"]: 18,
    ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
  };
  var person8 = {
    ["first-Name"]: "Ikki",
    ["last-Name"]: "Hyuga",
    ["age"]: 18,
    ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
  };
  anotherArr.push(person5, person6, person7, person8);

  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  anotherArr.forEach((person, i) => {
    var name = document.createElement('h4');
    var desc = document.createElement('p');
    var button = document.createElement('div');
    name.className = "lol";
    name.textContent = `${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
    desc.textContent = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
    frag.appendChild(name);
    frag.appendChild(desc);

  });
  parent.innerHTML = "";
  parent.appendChild(frag);
}


var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["first-Name"]: "John",
  ["last-Name"]: "Doe",
  ["age"]: 21,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};
var person3 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Sean",
  ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
  ["age"]: 32,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person4 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Ken",
  ["last-Name"]: "Chow",
  ["age"]: 12,
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var name = document.createElement('h4');
  var desc = document.createElement('p');
  var button = document.createElement('div');

  name.textContent = `${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
  desc.textContent = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
  frag.appendChild(name);
  frag.appendChild(desc);

});
parent.appendChild(frag);


function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.size {
  width: 50%;
}

a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

.lol {
  color: lime;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="size">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
    </div>
    <div id="People" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="line1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="updateTab()">Update Data!</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that looks great! but may i ask because i'm getting the new data from the server and replacing it with the original data like the above codes for my project is this the best way to do it?

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes. You can't use `replaceChild()` directly in this context, so clearing the original content and then adding the new content is probably your best bet. It's a super fast operation, so shouldn't be noticeable.